# div is hiding when close the popup in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am using Bootstrap 4 for modal(popup) in my application. I want to show div when I am closing the popup. But div is closing.

I am displaying div when the object is available, for example when I am clicking the button I am getting data from backend and I am displaying on div using `<div *ngIf="">--</div>`.

div is showing when we are using click button and displaying div. But I have an edit button in div. When I am clicking edit I have displayed popup using Bootstrap 4 modal at that time div is closing.

**Below is submit button. after I will pass to service and get json array is viewdata**

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search" [disabled]="!userForm.valid">
```

**checking array, showing correctly.**

```
<div *ngIf="viewdata"> 
    <table *ngFor="let mydata of viewdata.guestListArray; let i = index"> 
        <a >{{mydata.id}}</a>       
        <a title="Edit" (click)="open(editmodel)"> 
            <img src="/assets/images/edit-icon.png">
        </a> 
    </table> 
</div>
```

**when I am clicking on edit, popup displaying but table is not showing.**

```
<ng-template #editmodel let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div  class="model-footer">
        <span>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Submit</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: please put a demo, for help in your code.

Comment: you have a typo.. it needs to be `*ngIf`

Comment: I have added my code above please check. how to show table when i am closing the popup also

Comment: Please add the popup and table code, or even better, the whole page code

Comment: <div *ngIf="viewdata"> is not showing when i am closing the popup.  While click submit button in popup data is inserting and closing the popup and i am inserting data and getting same array "viewdata".

Comment: @suraj : typo mistake, help me to resolve the issue

Comment: your html seems to have a problem here: `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Submit</button>`

Comment: it's correct only, please check the below link i have used popup modal its working fine. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples. but my table div is closing(<div *ngIf="viewdata"> </div>)

Comment: `input` tag needs to be `button`

Comment: I will check and i will tell you Suraj

Comment: It's working suraj, Kindly add your answer, i will mark it as solved